# Adding tools to Stackshare

Tags: stackshare

It looks like this question has already been asked, but not answered: how do I add tools to stackshare? Is there some type of voting process?

Comment: Possible duplicate  - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110036/1512

Comment: Yes, but the previous question wasn't answered.

Comment: Hi Cody, someone was kind enough to edit the prior question, bumping it back to the front page.  With 75 reputation, you could put a bounty on that question to see if anyone is able to answer.  There's also the option of sharing a link to this question on social media or the like so that it gets more exposure.

Comment: Hopefully if someone sees your question in the near future, they will be kind enough to answer the original since it's linked above.

Comment: https://stackshare.io/vendors

Comment: https://stackshare.io/submit